# Como posso ajustar o tamanho da altura num box Wysiwyg

Tags: php, wordpress

Necessito usar Custom Post Types e aprendi como fazer [neste artigo](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/17625/wordpress/como_criar_custom_post_types_no_wordpress_30/).
Tem um porém, esse artigo não ensina como inserir Custom Post Types em Páginas e nem como deixar o `<textarea>` no formato Wysiwyg.
O que preciso:

1. Deixa-lo o `textearea` em Wysiwyg e ainda determinar o tamanho da altura `height`. Exemplo: `100px`, não quero ela grande, pois vai ser escrito pouca coisa, e são 3 caixa de texto.
2. Remover o Content principal, ou melhor deixar somente os Custom Post Types, remover o textearea que o Wordpress já vem por padrão.

Código functions.php utilizado, para incluir os Custom Post Types nas Páginas:

```
add_action("admin_init", "admin_init");

function admin_init(){
  add_meta_box("credits_meta", "Design & Build Credits", "credits_meta", "page", "normal", "low");
}

function credits_meta() {
  global $post;
  $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
  $designers = $custom["designers"][0];
  $developers = $custom["developers"][0];
  $producers = $custom["producers"][0];
  ?>
  <p><label>Designed By:</label><br />
  <textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="designers"><?php echo $designers; ?></textarea></p>
  <p><label>Built By:</label><br />
  <textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="developers"><?php echo $developers; ?></textarea></p>
  <p><label>Produced By:</label><br />
  <textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="producers"><?php echo $producers; ?></textarea></p>
  <?php
}
```

Até encontrei o código de inserir uma caixa de texto em Wysiwyg, porém como posso ajustar o tamanho da altura?

```
$content = '';
$editor_id = 'mycustomeditor';
wp_editor( $content, $editor_id );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função [`wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings = array() )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) tem um terceiro parâmetro que tem o ajuste que você precisa, `textarea_rows`.

Os valores padrão são:

```
$settings = array(
    'wpautop' => true,                     // use wpautop?
    'media_buttons' => true,               // show insert/upload button(s)
    'textarea_name' => $editor_id,         // set the textarea name to something different, square brackets [] can be used here
    'textarea_rows' => 20,
    'tabindex' => '',
    'tabfocus_elements' => ':prev,:next',  // the previous and next element ID to move the focus to when pressing the Tab key in TinyMCE
    'editor_css' => '',                    // intended for extra styles for both visual and Text editors buttons, needs to include the <style> tags, can use "scoped".
    'editor_class' => '',                  // add extra class(es) to the editor textarea
    'teeny' => false,                      // output the minimal editor config used in Press This
    'dfw' => false,                        // replace the default fullscreen with DFW (needs specific DOM elements and css)
    'tinymce' => true,                     // load TinyMCE, can be used to pass settings directly to TinyMCE using an array()
    'quicktags' => true                    // load Quicktags, can be used to pass settings directly to Quicktags using an array()
) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu recomendaria o uso do módulo Advanced Custom Fields, simplifica esse processo e funciona bem.

Com ele é possível criar campos específicos (como no seu caso, um campo testo com Wysiwyg) e associá-lo a um tipo de conteúdo. A forma de criação de templates específicos segue a padrão do wordpress como single-{post-type}.php

link para o módulo
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

Comment: Mesmo que este link seja uma boa sugestão, esta resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Por isso, e também porque é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui mesmo, seria melhor você responder com respostas mais completas. Você pode elaborar mais sua resposta? Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Respostas que apenas contêm links são boas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/705/respostas-que-apenas-contem-links-sao-boas)